# Как послать запрос к запущенному REST сервису, используя Jersey?

Tags: java-ee, rest

Например, есть REST-ресурс:

```
 @POST    
 @Path("/test")    
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response create(String content){

      ...
 }
```

Как для этого ресурса в клиенте составить запрос с помощью библиотеки Jersey?
Пример запроса:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/test
Authorization: Basic eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjIsInJvbGUiOiJDVVNUT01FUiIsImlzcyI6ImFwcDRwcm8ucnUifQ.rPfB4I-VdJ09ca5ogD5D6c1aYUtySAYAgjW8_TefZSY
Content-Type: application/json

*json content*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ в [документации](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html) (к сожалению, только на английском).

```
    public static void testRequest(){
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080").path("test");

        MyEntity myEntity = ... // создание кастомной сущности
        Entity<MyEntity> entity = Entity.entity(myEntity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Invocation.Builder ib = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        ib.header("Authorization", "Basic eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjIsInJvbGUiOiJDVVNUT01FUiIsImlzcyI6ImFwcDRwcm8ucnUifQ.rPfB4I-VdJ09ca5ogD5D6c1aYUtySAYAgjW8_TefZSY")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String response = ib.post(entity, String.class);            
        System.out.println(response);
    }
```

Или можно ещё так:

```
    public static void testRequest(){
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080").path("test");        

        Entity<String> entity = Entity.entity("*SomeString*", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Invocation.Builder ib = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        ib.header("Authorization", "Basic eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjIsInJvbGUiOiJDVVNUT01FUiIsImlzcyI6ImFwcDRwcm8ucnUifQ.rPfB4I-VdJ09ca5ogD5D6c1aYUtySAYAgjW8_TefZSY")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json");

        Response response = ib.post(entity);            
        System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
    }
```